# I want to disable the ability for people to type in the box, how can I do this with SimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

[sg.Output(size=(20, 5), key='*OUTPUT*', font=('Signore', 14), background_color='#000000')]

I currently have this to print/show the result but I am able to type in the box

I already tried readonly = true and looked but I can't find anything that restricts typing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's no argument `readonly=True` for `sg.Output`. Try to use `sg.Multiline(size=(20, 5), disabled=True, key='OUTPUT')`.